# How to select middle digits in an integer and have the other digits remain as an integer Python

Tags: python

For example, let's say I have a number that is 8 digits long, 12345678, I would like to select and take out the middle 4 digits, 3456, and then leave the remaining digits, 1278, as an integer.

Comment: How do you know how many digits to take?

Comment: Please define `middle digits`?  Give a few examples would be helpful.

Comment: Mind you, examples with even and odd number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it, after you transformed it to strings

```
pos_from = 2
pos_to = 6
data_as_integer = 12345678
data_as_string = str(data_as_integer)

sliced = int(data_as_string[pos_from:pos_to])
new_int = int(data_as_string[0:pos_from] + data_as_string[pos_to:len(data_as_string)])

print(sliced)
print(new_int)
```

output:

```
3456
1278
```

Comment: Yes, this is what was trying to do. I just realized another problem I need help with. How would you add a place holder of "0" in front of the digit if it was not 8 digits long? for example let's say we were given the number 1234567, how do you convert it to 01234567?

Comment: you can add `0` to `data_as_string` if the len of `data_as_integer` is not even

Comment: Alternatively, you can start counting from the end with negative indices, like `data_as_string[-pos_to:-pos_from]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x // 10**n` to cut last n digigts and `x % 10**n` to get last n digits of x.

combine this two operations you can get any part of original number.

But solution suggested by @D-E-N is probably simpler

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```py
num  = list(str(12345678))
gap = 2

startData = num[:gap] 
endData = num[len(num)-gap:]
middleData = num[gap:len(num)-gap]

print(
    startData+ endData,
    middleData,
)

sides = int( "".join(startData+ endData))
middle = int("".join(middleData))


print(
    sides,
    middle,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_my_integer(i):
    s = str(i)
    l = len(s) // 2
    pos = len(s) // 4
    s1, s2 = s[pos:pos+l], s[:pos] + s[pos+l:]
    return int(s1) if s1 else 0, int(s2) if s2 else 0
```

Here is a quick and dirty function which does what you want. Error-handling can be improved, but it should be basically operational.
The `return` line includes a quick check for empty strings, to help avoid throwing an exception.